# How to get multiple responses from a single ajax request?

Tags: javascript, ajax

.
        how to get multiple responses while passing single request to ajax.
        I'm struggling to use ajax concept.
        Can anyone share sample code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AJAX is Asynchronous JavaScript And XML. when you send a request to server you will get 1 response for it, you need to be clearfy your concept about asynchronous http calls.

Asynchoronous calls means, for example you send two requests two server named as Request1 and Request2 but you may receive response for Request2 first then for Request1.

### Sample Code for multiple requests:

```
<script>
function firstMethod(){
$.ajax({
  url: "http://localhost3000/firstmethod",
  data: {"data1":"abc"},
  success: function(){
    alert("Response for first request")
},
  dataType: "Application/JSON"
});
}

function secondMethod(){
$.ajax({
  url: "http://localhost3000/secondmethod",
  data: {"data2":"def"},
  success: function(){
    alert("Response for second request")
},
  dataType: "Application/JSON"
});
}
</script>
```

### HTML

```
<button onclick="firstMethod()">First Request</button>
<button onclick="secondMethod()">Second Request</button>
```

Comment: oh i see . know only i know about this clearly. thanks for ur concern dear wasif Khan

Comment: @ClamentChristopherE Anytime, please accept this answer as well :)

Comment: can u send any sample code how to send multiple request and get multiple responses

Comment: okay, I will write sample code of jquery.

Comment: Thanks for ur good response dear Wasif Khan

Comment: When i use this JSON code it shows some error  'Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined'. I think i have to import jquery file. But which of the import file i want? @wasif Khan

Comment: use this one.
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>